# string(16) "error code: 1020" - cURl issue php

Tags: php, curl

I tried to log in to the website with cURL. But I faced `string(16) "error code: 1020"`. I was wondering how I can resolve this issue.

```
$data = array(
    "utf8"=>"✓",
    "authenticity_token"=>"token",
    "user[email]"=>"aaaaaa@email.com.au",
    "user[password]"=>"password",
    "user[remember_me]"=>"0",
    "commit"=>"Sign+in"
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://app.kajabi.com/login");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo '<pre>';
echo die(var_dump($response));
echo '</pre>';
```

The below image is from Chrome.

[image]

Comment: We can't really answer questions what specific error codes from random websites mean. You need to check with the site owner.

Comment: so do I need to talk with Kajabi staff?

Comment: Yes. We can't possibly know how their site works. We can help you if you have a programming question, but not if you have questions how different sites/services works. This isn't a generic helpdesk for everything online. My guess would be that `authenticity_token` is some [CSRF protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery), which is for preventing people from doing what you're tryign to do.